# "Unknown PdfException" by iText7 when TimeStampToken is not present in the embedded Pkcs7 UnsignedAttributes section

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, itext7, pkcs#7, pades

I'm using itext7-dotnet 8.0.2 and I'm getting an "Unknown PdfException" from `PdfPKCS7` constructor when the Pkcs7 has an unsigned attributes section without a TimeStampToken attribute:

```
iText.Kernel.Exceptions.PdfException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Unknown PdfException.
Source=itext.sign
StackTrace:
    at iText.Signatures.SignatureUtil.ReadSignatureData(String signatureFieldName)
    ...

    This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
        iText.Bouncycastle.Asn1.Cms.AttributeBC.GetAttrValues()
        iText.Signatures.PdfPKCS7.PdfPKCS7(byte[], iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfName)
```

As far as I understand, the PAdES specs don't mandate the presence of the TimeStampToken attribute if unsigned attributes exist in the SignerInfo structure.

If for example I just include an UnstructuredName with some custom info among the unsigned attributes, the [ETSI online validator](https://signatures-conformance-checker.etsi.org/protected/upload.php?sigtype=padesconf) (registration required) only reports a warning:
"An unknown attribute, defined by OID 1.2.840.113549.1.9.2 has been reached. Its contents and their processing are unknown to the AdESCC. No further checks will be done to this component"

Looking at itext7-dotnet source code I noticed that when parsing the unsigned attributes section it tries to extract the id-aa-timeStampToken (1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.14) and checks the returned `IAttribute` instance to be not null and having values, but the `IAttributeTable.Get(IDerObjectIdentifier oid)` method of the itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter library doesn't check the actual existence of the OID-specified attribute in the table and instead returns a new instance of `AttributeBC` with a null value argument, causing the following `GetAttrValues()` in the PdfPKCS7 constructor to fail.

By reading the iText7 Java version of that same code it seems the same issue should be present there as well, though I didn't test it.

Comment: Please share an example signed PDF with which one can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @mkl you can use this [sample PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v0zBc-YW-3VmANTms33gSa8mu5QVrjDG/view).

Comment: Indeed, there is a regression: If the signature container has unsigned attributes but not a timestamp attribute among them, the code runs into an exception due to a method call on a `null` object. It's just fairly seldom that a signature has unsigned attributes but not a timestamp one, so the error has not popped up before. iText development will be informed.